# How can I use batch to determine what version of windows a computer is runing?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, wmic

While scripting it is necessary to determine what version of Windows a computer is running. The only issue is that **Windows-10 and Server-2016** have the same ***version number***.

This is the code currently. In this state, Windows10 and Server2016 are identified with the same number `wmic os get` outputs `10.0.18329`  (which doesn't work).

```bat
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set Operating=%%i.%%j
if "%Operating%" == "6.3" set Operating=Windows81
if "%Operating%" == "6.2" set Operating=Windows8
if "%Operating%" == "10.0" set Operating=Windows10
if "%Operating%" == "10.0" set Operating=Server2016
echo Is %Operating% your operating system?
```

---

> What I would like to do is parse`wmic os get name` to get the OS name. This is showing some challenges because the output is multiple lines and there is an arbitrary number of characters before and after the OS name ('Windows 10').

---

This is the output of `wmic os get name` on windows 10 pro:

```bat
Name
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk1\Partition3
```

This is the output of `wmic os get name` on Server 2016:

```bat
Name                                                                       
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard|C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2
```

Comment: What is stopping you from capturing the output with a `FOR /F` command just like you did with the `VER` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you've already chosen a solution, but if this is related to the last question you asked, *now deleted*, where you're only trying to determine between `Windows 8`, `Windows 8.1`, `Windows 10` and `Windows Server 2016` then I would have suggested something along these lines:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "_S="
For /F "EOL=P Tokens=*" %%A In ('"WMIC OS Get ProductType,Version 2>Nul"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=. " %%B In ("%%A") Do Set /A _S=%%B,_V=%%C%%D
If Not Defined _S Exit /B
If %_V% Lss 62 Exit /B
If %_S% Equ 1 (If %_V% Equ 62 Set "_S=Windows8"
    If %_V% Equ 63 Set "_S=Windows81"
    If %_V% Equ 100 Set "_S=Windows10"
) Else If %_V% Equ 100 (Set "_S=Server2016") Else Exit /B
Set _S
Pause
Exit /B
```

---

**[Edit /]**

…and for a generic method, you may find this useful, especially the use of the `Caption` property, *(which I'd suggest is much better than using the `Name` property, splitting it at the first pipe character, running it through another `For` loop then removing one or more trailing space characters)*.:

```bat
@For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC OS Get Caption/Format:MOF')Do Set "_S=%%A"
```

To test it just add a second line:

```bat
@Set _S&Pause
```

Note: This method may have issues on some earlier operating systems due to a bug preventing them finding the location of the `.xsl` file. *There are workarounds for this, either copy the `.xsl` files from your 'language' directory up a level, or provide the full path to the `.xsl` file, e.g. `/Format:"%__AppDir__%wbem\en-US\MOF.xsl"`.*

Comment: @compo.. Luckily you saw the previous answer and could provide a better solution, I will upvote on behalf of OP.

Comment: @Cutwow, I have added an edit to my answer, because I think that the answer you think will help others more can be improved upon by using a different property. _…and for those with the ability to view deleted questions, [here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520701) which initially prompted my answer_.

Answer (score 3):

How about just straight forward...

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims=|" %%i in ('wmic os get name') do echo %%i & exit /b
```

Comment: That's another great solution. +1. You should optionally add a `pause` to see the value if it will be run with double-click.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=| " %%A IN ('wmic os get name') do (
    set "os=%%A %%B %%C"
)

echo You are using %os%.
```

Another possible solution to include all versions of Windows:

```bat
@echo off

for /F "skip=1 delims=|" %%A IN ('wmic os get name') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        set "os=%%B"
    )
)

echo You are using %os:Microsoft =%.
pause
exit /b
```

Which will extract OS, substracting `Microsoft<space>` at the end in both cases.

In the second case, two loops are used, since `wmic` has **unusual line *endings*** (`<CR><CR><LF>`).

Comment: @double-beep yes, but code blocks can become slower, more for loops as well. In the case below, The item is set each time the loop is run, but the carriage return line feed is set as a variable, so the last will always be set as the variable name, hence it is easier to set it once, then exit the loop, no code blocks needed. Anyway, was just trying to help, you got the green mark already. :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `ver` command, here is an example:

```
@echo off
for /f "useback delimes=;" %%a in (`ver`) do set ver=%%a
echo The computer version your running is %ver%
```

Use the variable `%ver%` as the version you are running, I use it to `echo` the version but you can do anything with it

Comment: The OP explicitly mentioned, that `ver` doesn't work, because Windows10 and Windows-Server 2016 shows the same version number